# Interpreting non-latin characters in Sinatra coming from Mac Excel 2011

Tags: ruby, excel, vba, character-encoding, sinatra

I've a Mac VBA script making a request to a Ruby Sinatra web app.

The text passing from Excel contains characters such as é. Ruby (version 1.9.2) chokes on these characters as Excel is not sending them as UTF-8.

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'rubygems'

require 'sinatra'
require "sinatra/reloader" if development?

configure do
  class << Sinatra::Base
    def options(path, opts={}, &block)
      route 'OPTIONS', path, opts, &block
    end
  end
  Sinatra::Delegator.delegate :options
end

options '/' do
  response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
  response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST"

  halt 200
end

post '/fetch' do
  chars = []
  params['excel_input'].valid_encoding?  #returns false
  params['excel_input']
end
```

My Excel VBA:

```vb
Sub FetchAddress()
    For Each oDest In Selection
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;http://localhost:4567/fetch", Destination:=oDest)
            .PostText = "excel_input=" & oDest.Offset(0, -1).Value
            .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
            .SaveData = True
            .Refresh
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

The character é comes out the other end as Ž.

It looks like the text in Excel is encoded as Windows-1252 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252.

The byte representation of the character is 142 (or Ž in Windows-1252).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iconv can convert the input to UTF-8. It converts the character encoding from one encoding to another. So something like this should work:

```
require "iconv"
...
post '/fetch' do
  excel_input = Iconv.conv("UTF-8", "WINDOWS-1252", params['excel_input'])
  ...
end
```

Comment: It didn't like it. I think the problem is that the text coming in is not windows-1252...I have no idea what encoding it's coming in as.

Comment: Two problems in the code above: 1. UTF8 should be UTF-8  2. Order of parameters should be TO, FROM.

Comment: This was close enough to get me to what I needed. I figured out that the input was coming in as MACROMAN. Alas, I still can't print back to the Excel properly.

Comment: Cool. Sorry to mislead you with the wrong arguments. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

you can also probably look at: https://github.com/jmhodges/rchardet
then, you can autodetect charset and then convert it to utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

[Ruby 1.9 Encodings: A Primer and the Solution for Rails - yehuda katz](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/05/ruby-1-9-encodings-a-primer-and-the-solution-for-rails/) is a good read. If you have some time. Goes in to depth about encodings and how to convert between them.

Comment: Thanks, I've read through it and it's quite an interesting post, though doesn't quite help here.